# Display data in a popup window in ASP.NET using jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, window, modal-dialog

I am making an ASP.NET application. I have a page which displays a list of data [as a GridView].

I need to display a list of objects [as a GridView] in a new view over the current view, not a new window but a kind of AJAX popup, so that the context shiftes on the page to the new view/form!!

Shall i use Modal Window for this? If so, how shall I do it, as the function to open the modal shall be fired when an item of the GridView is selected?
Is there any plugin which can simplify my task?

Comment: You should check out Greybox Redux (or the jQuery port), in a nutshell it's a modal window that loads a separate page into an iFrame.  Once you load your GridVeiw into the Grebox modal window, you can use server side postbacks to do your updates.  When your done, you can have the modal close button trigger updates to the current page behind the modal window.  Here's a link to an example: http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/greybox/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good plugin called blockUI for jQuery that will let you achieve this quite easily.

You can use it to show any HTML that you desire or even load an iFrame using that. You can download this plugin and find examples here

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

If you post some sample code I can probably help you create your modal pop up!

Please do vote up my answer or mark the checkbox next to it, if I helped you at all. Thanks :)

Comment: This is the answer as I preferred this than the AJAXControlToolkit.

Answer (score 2):

You could always try the ASP.net Ajax Control Toolkit

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

It supported by the ASP.net team and it's really easy to use!